# Open URL from JavaScript after user has entered details

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, window.open

I need to prevent a user from downloading a file (PDF) until they have entered some simple details into a form. We need to capture the details so that we can see who is downloading the file.

See a jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ctn7N/1/

The steps I need it to follow are:

1. User opens page. If they have already filled out the capture form, store that state in a variable.
2. They click a download link. Store the link so that it can be used later.
3. If they've already entered details, i.e. check the variable, open the link in a new tab as normal (default behaviour).
4. If they haven't entered details, show the capture form.
5. Once they click submit on the form, show the downloads section again, store the state and open the original download that they clicked on in a new tab.
6. On subsequent loads of the page they should not have to enter their details again and downloads should just open.

The current code I'm using fails at the last part of step 5, when it tries to open the download link in a new tab. Although it works in the fiddle, it breaks in Chrome v35.0 because the link is blocked by a popup blocker.

Is there any way around this that would allow it to open in all browsers?

Thanks for looking,

Adam

Code to accompany fiddle:

HTML Code

```
<div id="capture-section" class="hide">
    <form id="capture-form">
        <label for="name">Enter your name to download the file:</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
        <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="download-section">
    <!-- Download links replaced with placeholder links for jsFiddle, would normally be PDFs -->
    <a target="_blank" class="js-download" href="http://example.com">Document 1</a>
    <a target="_blank" class="js-download" href="http://www.google.com">Document 2</a>
    <a target="_blank" class="js-download" href="http://www.bing.com">Document 3</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var detailsEntered = '',
        downloadLink = '';

    // Would normally access localStorage on load of page to see if user has already entered details
    // Removed to allow multiple jsFiddle runs for a user
    //
    // detailsEntered = accessStorage('retrieve', 'detailsEntered');

    $('.js-download').click(function(event) {
        var self = $(this);
        downloadLink = self.attr('href'); // Store clicked download link
        if (detailsEntered != 'true') {
            // If the user hasn't entered details yet, show the form
            $('#download-section').addClass('hide');
            $('#capture-section').removeClass('hide');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } // Otherwise allow standard link behviour
    });

    $("#submit-btn").click(function(event) {
        var name = $('input[name=name]').val(),
            proceed = true;

        if(name==""){
            $('input[name=name]').addClass("error");
            proceed = false;
        }

        if(proceed) {
            // If form validates, show downloads again and store value for return visits
            $('#capture-form input').val('');
            $('#capture-section').addClass('hide');
            $('#download-section').removeClass('hide');
            detailsEntered = 'true';
            accessStorage('store', 'detailsEntered', 'true');

            // Now open previously clicked download link in new tab
            // DOES NOT WORK - Blocked by popup blocker
            window.open(downloadLink, '_blank');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("input, textarea").keyup(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    });

    function accessStorage(action, dataKey, dataValue) {
        if(typeof(Storage) === "undefined") {
            // No support for localStorage/sessionStorage.
            return false;
        } 
        if (action == 'store') {
            localStorage.setItem(dataKey, dataValue);
        } else if (action == 'retrieve') {
            return localStorage.getItem(dataKey);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you put the download link into the HTML, the whole mechanism of "protecting" it becomes useless since everyone who can right-click a page will be able to download the files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, if you don't need to open a new page, would be to simply change the location of the current page (means no popup issue) :

```
    if(proceed) {
        // If form validates, show downloads again and store value for return visits
        $('#capture-form input').val('');
        $('#capture-section').addClass('hide');
        $('#download-section').removeClass('hide');
        detailsEntered = 'true';
        accessStorage('store', 'detailsEntered', 'true');

        // Now open previously clicked download link in new tab
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + downloadLink; // if downloadLink is a relative URI
        // window.location.href = downloadLink; // if downloadLink is an absolute URI
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does need to open in a new page. Otherwise this would be a great answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Now the accepted answer as the client changed their mind on opening in a new tab. Thanks again!

Comment: glad that could help you ;)